Cannot query LookupFilter by SourceFieldDefinitionId. Tooling API bug?
The Tooling API docs for LookupFilter list the field SourceFieldDefinitionId as "filterable", but any query I run while trying to filter that field returns no rows.
For example, this query to list all active LookupFilters on a specific custom object returns one result:

However, this query using the SourceFieldDefinitionId returned from the prior query returns no rows:

This makes no sense to me; the primary use case for querying LookupFilter would be to retrieve the Metadata field for the active filter (if any) for a given field, which I can only specify by SourceFieldDefinitionId (and which I would first retrieve by querying ToolingAPI object FieldDefinition). Given these results, I'll need to instead query all LookupFilters for the object (query by SourceObject), iterate the results to look for the SourceFieldDefinitionId I want, and then query again by Id to get the Metadata column (queries including the Metadata field are limited to 1 result).
Is this a bug, or is there some other requirement that I'm missing?
Note:  I've used Developer Console for simplicity here, but I've run the same queries against the ToolingAPI query endpoint directly, with the same results.
